# Asyncronous function not changing variable in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, asynchronous, scope

```
var encodedAccount = '';
function encodeUsername() 
{
    encodedAccount=  encrypt(document.getElementById('account').value);
    alert(encodedAccount);
}
```

the function encrypt is async ajax function. the `alert` is not returning a value , it's still ''
Any Idea ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Asynchronous functions generally don't return values. They usually accept a callback function that fires when the function is done (usually when when HTTP response comes back in the case of Ajax).

You need to find out how the `encrypt` function expects to be used and conform to its expectations.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I will review the function and try to use callback